# Using jQuery '.eq()' with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I properly use the 'eq' function on multiple classes?  Because, the div's with class 'a' are not subsequent, I cannot use the 'eq' function to updated their class.  If the divs with class "b", are removed, the function works perfectly.  Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9w8zhg7d/4/. I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="a current">
</div>
<div class="a">
</div>
<div class="b">
</div>
<div class="b">
</div>
<div class="a">
</div>
<div class="a">
</div>
```

and the following javascript:

```
Class = {
    a: ".a",
    highlighted: ".a.current",
    init: function() {
        $(this.a).click(this.toggleA.bind(this));
    },
    toggleA: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this.highlighted).removeClass("current");
        var target = $(e.target);
        var clickedA = target.closest(this.a);
        var clickedIndex = clickedA.index();
        $(".a").eq(clickedIndex).addClass("current");
        console.log(clickedIndex);
        $(".b").eq(clickedIndex).css("display", "inline-block");
    }
};

Class.init();
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `.eq()` doesn't work with *classes* at all, it works on whatever elements are in your jQuery object. So if you want to apply it across all `.a` and `.b` elements just select them all: `$(".a,.b").eq(x)`. (Having said that, I don't understand what you're trying to do. Your example has four a's and only two b's, so I don't see how the elements relate to each other. I don't understand your use of `.closest()` either, but it doesn't look right because in the html shown all elements are siblings.)

Comment: I'm curious-what are you trying to accomplish? It may be that using `.eq` might not be the best option if we know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you look at the fiddle, you will see that clicking on the first two a's works properly, but the third and fourth a's do not get the 'current' class when clicked.  Remove, the 'b' divs and the function works for all a's.  I want it to work that way with the 'b' divs in the mix.

Comment: So why not simplify to this: https://jsfiddle.net/9w8zhg7d/5/ - as I said before, using `.closest()` doesn't make sense. I don't understand what you're trying to do with the `clickedIndex` applying to the `.b` elements, because the number of `.a` and `.b` elements are different.

Comment: I am sorry, I simplified the fiddle and code to make it quicker, but didn't realize I removed the main point.  The clicked element is not what will be getting the current class, but rather another set of div's.  That is why I need to get the clicked index and apply it (via 'eq') to the index of another set of divs

Comment: @JordanBarber can you explain in simple words what are you trying to achieve? what is supposed to happen when we click on a '.a' box and what should happen when we click on a '.b' box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know the index of the particular `.a` element that was clicked, ignoring all other elements. If so you just have to use the [`.index()` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/) correctly:

```
var clickedIndex = $(this.a).index(e.target);
```

When you call `.index()` with no arguments as in your code, it finds the index of the first element in the jQuery object relative to its siblings, not relative to other elements in the jQuery object. The code I've shown says to first select all of the `.a` elements, then within those elements only figure out the position of the `e.target` element.

You've also overcomplicated the setting of the `current` class - it doesn't make sense to use `.closest()`, because that is for navigating up through the DOM and all of your elements are siblings. You can just say:

```
$(e.target).addClass("current");
```

I don't understand how you want to apply the index of the clicked `.a` element to the `.b` elements, because there are four `.a`'s and only two `.b`'s, but still putting what I've said above together with your code gives something like this:

```js
Class = {
  a: ".a",
  highlighted: ".a.current",
  init: function() {
    $(this.a).click(this.toggleA.bind(this));
  },
  toggleA: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this.highlighted).removeClass("current");
    var target = $(e.target).addClass("current");
    var clickedIndex = $(this.a).index(e.target);
    console.log(clickedIndex);
    $(".b").removeClass("current").eq(clickedIndex).addClass("current");
    $(".c").removeClass("current").eq(clickedIndex).addClass("current");
  }
}

Class.init();
```

```css
.a,.b { width:50px; height:50px; background:black; display:inline-block; }
.c { width:20px; height:20px; background:blue; display:inline-block; }
.a.current{ background:red; }
.c.current, .b.current{ background:green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a current"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="related">
  <div class="c"></div> <div class="c"></div> <div class="c"></div> <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

(Or an updated version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9w8zhg7d/8/)

Comment: I am sorry, I simplified the fiddle and code to make it quicker, but didn't realize I removed the main point.  The clicked element is not what will be getting the current class, but rather another set of div's.  That is why I need to get the clicked index and apply it (via 'eq') to the index of another set of divs

Comment: Right. But I think the code in my answer shows exactly how to do that. You can see as you click on the `a` elements the correct index appears in the console, and it also updates the corresponding `b` elements... So just adapt that demo to your real situation. Looks like the main problem you had was you weren't quite using `.index()` correctly for that scenario.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add an extra set of elements to better simulate your real situation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I feel like the solution you're proposing may be overcomplicated. Have you considered this solution?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a current"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.container > div {
  width:50px;
  margin: 1em;
  height:50px;
  background:black;
}

.a.current{
  background:red;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.container > div').on('click', function() {
    $('.container > div').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass('current')
});
```

This will just apply `.current` to the one clicked and while removing it from all. Targeting the parent allows you to have that functionality without needing to work with the class specificity of the children div's.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9w8zhg7d/7/

Comment: Don't forget `.a.current` should be `.container > div.current` in CSS now :)

Comment: @Aziz Yah, I thought about it. But I wasn't sure his original intention so I just left it like that. Perhaps he is leaving styling for `.b.current`? Shrug.